# No microcode detected after installation and reboot

Tags: server, intel-cpu, microcode

I noticed an error in GCP log:

```
[    0.294304] MMIO Stale Data: Vulnerable: Clear CPU buffers attempted, no microcode
```

After installation, I then ran these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install microcode.ctl intel-microcode
sudo reboot now
```

However, running  `sudo dmesg | grep microcode` still states that there is *no microcode* (see image below).

[image]

System specs:

> System: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-1025-gcp x86_64)
> CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU @ 2.20GHz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not an error message, but a status message related to the "Processor MMIO Stale Data Vulnerabilities".

From [Kernel.org documentation](https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/hw-vuln/processor_mmio_stale_data.html):

> ##### Mitigation status information
>
> The Linux kernel provides a sysfs interface to enumerate the current
> vulnerability status of the system: whether the system is vulnerable,
> and which mitigations are active. The relevant sysfs file is:
>
> ```
> /sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/mmio_stale_data
> ```
>
> The possible values in this file are:
>
> | Value | Status |
> | --- | --- |
> | ‘Not affected’ | The processor is not vulnerable |
> | ‘Vulnerable’ | The processor is vulnerable, but no mitigation enabled |
> | ‘Vulnerable: Clear CPU buffers attempted, no microcode’ | The processor is vulnerable, but microcode is not updated. The mitigation is enabled on a best effort basis. |
> | ‘Mitigation: Clear CPU buffers’ | The processor is vulnerable and the CPU buffer clearing mitigation is enabled. |
> | ‘Unknown: No mitigations’ | The processor vulnerability status is unknown because it is out of Servicing period. Mitigation is not attempted. |

So this is basically a service message that tells you that your CPU has this vulnerability, and that there isn't a microcode fix for it installed.

It seems you have the latest microcode packages installed - so I suppose a full fix isn't possible for that CPU at this time.